# Python: cv2.imshow without waitKey()

Tags: python, opencv3.0

I am trying to find a way to show an image without the dependency of waitKey(). I want the image to be shown and continue on with next operations (like a plot using matplotlib). How can this be achieved?

Comment: use `cv::waitKey(1)`

Answer (score 2):

If you're wanting to show the window and have the program continue execution without relying on `cv2.waitKey()`, then `cv2.startWindowThread()` is what you're looking for.

Example:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("C:\\Test\\so1.png")
cv2.imshow("Test", img)
cv2.startWindowThread()

for x in range(0, 10000000):
    print(x)
```

This will display the image and continue execution without using `waitKey`

Answer (score 0):

I tried multiple methods, but what worked was using matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#obtain I as a numpy array
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(I, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
```